# Enviar dados de um banco para outro

Tags: php, mysql

Existe alguma maneira de eu enviar dados de um banco para outro? Se sim, como eu poderia faze-lo? Exemplo: Tenho o site 1, ele envia dados para o banco 1, esses dados chegam no 1 e automaticamente são enviados para o banco 2, e o site 2 exibe os dados que foram enviados para o banco 2.

Comment: envia pro dois direto, ao invés de um banco pro outro

Comment: A questão é que eu preciso fazer desse jeito, quem dera fosse simples assim :/

Comment: Essa aqui seria uma alternativa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370970/how-to-create-linked-server-mysql